# Right-angled triangles with integer sides a,b.c,less than 100 such that:c*c=a*a+b*b

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$$5*5=3*3+4*4$$

```
Integers a,b,c
For a=1 to 100
For b=1 to 100
For c=1 to 100
if c*c=a*a+b*b
list a.b,c
Next c
Next b
Next a
```

## I am 74.

I am interested in youth-hood practical mathematics.
Child can use strings of 3,4,5 to draw a right-angled triangle.
This 3,4,5 triangle also shows a short-cut 5,saves 3+4 by 2.
I come across this site by chance.
I even forget the Language I used some 50 years ago.
I would be very much obliged to be enlighted on this question.

Comment: There is a simple formula that gives all solutions to $a^2+b^2=c^2$: $a=2kmn$, $b=k(m^2-n^2)$, $c=k(m^2+n^2)$, $m,n,k$ arbitrary integers. Or type "pythagorean triples" into the web, I'm sure you'll find that someone has tabulated everything you want.

Comment: Wikipedia's ["Pythagorean triple" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Examples) lists "primitive" triples with $c \leq 300$. ("Primitive" triples have no common factors.)

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Most of our new users are students looking for homework answers.  It's nice to hear from adults still curious about learning and sharing mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for what are called "Pythagorean triples": sets of integers satisfying $a^2+b^2=c^2$. There is a formula for generating *all* such sets of integers, and you can read all about it in the Wikipedia article: [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Near the top of that article is a list which is almost precisely what you are looking for. The only difference is this: if we have a triple such as $(3,4,5)$, you can obtain others by multiplying all three numbers by the same factor, i.e., we have $(6,8,10)$, $(9,12,15)$, etc. These multiples are not included in the list at Wikipedia (they are not what we call "primitive"), but you can find them all without too much work.

Comment: Volks,thank you very much! This site open my mind to,.,,,

Comment: Volks,thank you very much;this site opens my mind to,,,,

Comment: If you are happy with Tony's answer, wengweng, you can "accept" it by clicking in the checkmark box next to it.